# Struggling with "syntax error in FROM clause"

Tags: c#, ms-access-2010

```
string type = "Cash";
string type1 = "Card";
if (radioButton1.Checked)
{
    myDB.Open();
    OleDbDataAdapter adapter = new OleDbDataAdapter(@"SELECT * FROM Transaction", myDB);
    adapter.Fill(dt);
    OleDbCommand cmd = new OleDbCommand(@"INSERT INTO Transaction(Type, Amount) Values ('" + type + "', " + label3.Text + ")", myDB);
    cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
}
else if(radioButton2.Checked)
{
    OleDbDataAdapter adapter = new OleDbDataAdapter(@"SELECT * FROM Transaction", myDB);
    adapter.Fill(dt);
    OleDbCommand cmd = new OleDbCommand(@"INSERT INTO Transaction(Type, Amount) Values ('" + type1 + "', " + label3.Text + ")", myDB);
    cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
}
myDB.Close();
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please read [ask] and how to create [mcve].

Answer (score 2):

Transaction is a SQL keyword! You need to put it in square brackets:

```
string type = "Cash";
string type1 = "Card";
if (radioButton1.Checked)
{
  myDB.Open();
  OleDbDataAdapter adapter = new OleDbDataAdapter(@"SELECT * FROM [Transaction]", myDB);
  adapter.Fill(dt);
  OleDbCommand cmd = new OleDbCommand(@"INSERT INTO [Transaction](Type, Amount) Values ('" + type + "', " + label3.Text + ")", myDB);
  cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
}
else if(radioButton2.Checked)
{
  OleDbDataAdapter adapter = new OleDbDataAdapter(@"SELECT * FROM [Transaction]", myDB);
adapter.Fill(dt);
  OleDbCommand cmd = new OleDbCommand(@"INSERT INTO [Transaction](Type, Amount) Values ('" + type1 + "', " + label3.Text + ")", myDB);
  cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
}
myDB.Close();
```

Comment: Done: Sorry took me 5 min to get the answer formatted properly

Comment: That's much better, we all take time to get used to that formatting